# Using KSEG2 with wired TLB's in kernel mode

Tags: c, linux, embedded, mips, embedded-linux

We have some code running in KUSEG and we see the need for more than 2Gb of memory that KUSEG provides. We tried to map some more physical memory into KSEG2 (since we run in kernel mode) by setting up wired TLBs. When I wrote a test application to access and write to the KSEG2 space (address 0xC0000000) I see that it throws a TLBS exception complaining that there is a TLB miss. I have double checked that the TLB's are setup correctly.
Am I missing something here. Has anyone used MIPS KSEG2 in kernel mode.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Vamsi.

Comment: No one? :( .. was hoping someone from the community would chime in ...

Answer (score 0):

On the chip we were using the KSEG2 address needs to have the high order 32 bits set to 1. Programming the virtual address as 0xFFFFFFFFC0000000 solved the problem.